# Elasticsearch - full text search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to match "new york" in a search (not places containing "new" or "york" separately)

here is my current query:

```
"query" : {                        
    "query_string" : {            
        "query" : "new york" ,
        "fields" : ["city"]
    }
},
"filter" : {
    "and" : [{
        "query" : {                 
            "query_string" : {                    
                "query" : "country:US"               
             }            
        }
    }]
}
```

However this keeps returning places named "york" rather than "new york"

I am not fully understanding how this works and would appreciate some help in getting this to actually work for me.

Comment: I don't know elasticsearch but my guess would be that the space in `"new york"` acts as a boolean or operator. Try `"\"new york\""` maybe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it doesn't appear to work when i do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want both words to appear in the same document you need to change the default operator like this:

```
"query" : {                        
    "query_string" : {            
        "query" : "new york" ,
        "fields" : ["city"],
        "default_operator" : "AND"
    }
}
```

or specify it ion the query:

```
"query" : {                        
    "query_string" : {            
        "query" : "new AND york" ,
        "fields" : ["city"]
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [query string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html) documentation.

Otherwise, if you want both words to appear close to each other in the same document you need to make a [phrase query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query.html) like this:

```
"query" : {
    "match_phrase" : {
        "message" : "new york"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the city field in "analyzed" by Elasticsearch which does the default tokenization of words.

```
New York => *New*, *York*
```

In order to keep the tokens intact (mostly used for aggregation), you need to explicitly make the city field "not analyzed" using multi field

```
'city' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            'fields' => [
            'raw' => [
              'type'  => 'string',
              'index' => 'not_analyzed'
              ]
            ]
        ]
```

Now you can use `city.raw` to get non analyzed values.